# cv2.findContours() acts strangely?

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I'm finding contours in an image. With every contour I found, I print out its bouding rect and area and then draw it to the image. Funnily, I found that 5 contours that have been drawed while there were only 4 contours printed. Anyone knows what happened here?

```
>>contour 1
>>(0, 0, 314, 326)
>>101538.5
>>contour 2
>>(75, 117, 60, 4)
>>172.0
>>contour 3
>>(216, 106, 3, 64)
>>124.0
>>contour 4
>>(62, 18, 138, 9)
>>383.5
```

[image]
[image]

```
import cv2 
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('1.png')

imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(imgray,127,255,0)

_, contours, hier = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i,c in enumerate(contours):
    rect = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    print("contour " + str(i+1))
    print(rect)
    print(area)

cv2.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 1)

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cv2.RETR_TREE` is the reason you are getting this. It retrieves all the contours and creates a full family hierarchy list. In contour detection you are expected to use white objects in black background. Otherwise because of hierarchy list you would get results as you are getting now. For more details check [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d9/d8b/tutorial_py_contours_hierarchy.html).

So make sure you find contours of **white objects in black background**. Add `cv2.bitwise_not()` function to convert the image.

.
.
.

```
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.bitwise_not(imgray,imgray)
```

.
.
.

**OUTPUT:**

[image]
  [image]

```
4
contour 1
(76, 118, 58, 2)
56.0
contour 2
(217, 107, 1, 62)
0.0
contour 3
(63, 19, 136, 7)
110.5
contour 4
(248, 1, 66, 45)
55.5
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I still wonder why it draws contour of the line but don't print it out.

Comment: In your case also there are only 4 contours. `Top right contour` is attached to the boundary of the image. So It is considered as a single contour along with the boundary.